# For what natural numbers n is $φ(n) ≡ 4 \pmod 8$?

Tags: number-theory

For what natural numbers n is $φ(n) ≡ 4 \pmod 8$?

For this question, first I think that I should consider in two cases. For the first case is that for n is odd number, and the second case is that $n$ is even. But I do not know how to determine how many prime factors does $n$ have in each case.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is the function you use the totient function?

Comment: Well. For all odd primes $p$ we have $2\mid\phi(p)=p-1$. For some odd primes we even have  $4\mid \phi(p)$, and for some $8\mid\phi(p)$. Undoubtedly you also know $\phi(2^n)$. Observe that for odd primes $p$ we have $\phi(p^n)=\phi(p)\cdot m$ where $m$ is an odd number. You should be able to do this by putting all these pieces together. Not all prime factors are equal for the purposes of this exercise :-)

Comment: I didn't learn what is totient function yet. Sorry

Comment: I still have no clue. Since I am not sure how to start it. Thanks

Comment: What does the function you have do? For example, how would you find $φ(6)$ or $φ(7)$?

Comment: Ok I see. Yes, I use the totient function.

Comment: Well, what do you know about the totient function?  Do you, say, know how to compute it from the prime factorization?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that factorization of $n$ is needed to determine if $\varphi(n)\equiv 4\pmod 8$. Any number $n$ with three or more odd prime different factors holds $8\mid\varphi(n)$. So $n$ is of one of the following forms
$$\begin{align}
n=2^rp^sq^t&\to\varphi(n)=2^{r-1}(p-1)p^{s-1}(q-1)q^{t-1}\\
n=2^rp^s&\to\varphi(n)=2^{r-1}(p-1)p^{s-1}\\
n=p^sq^t&\to\varphi(n)=(p-1)p^{s-1}(q-1)q^{t-1}\\
n=p^s&\to\varphi(n)=(p-1)p^{s-1}\\
n=2^r&\to\varphi(n)=2^{r-1}
\end{align}$$
where $p$ and $q$ are odd, different primes and $r,s,t\ge 1$.

If $r>3$ then $8\mid\varphi(n)$, so in this case the congruence can't hold.

If $r=3$ then $n=8$.

If $r=2$ then $n$ must have exactly one odd prime factor $p$ and $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

If $r=1$ or $n$ is odd then there are more possibilities. If $n$ has two odd prime factors $p$ and $q$, it must be $p\equiv q\equiv 3\pmod 4$. If $n$ has only one prime factor $p$ it must be $p\equiv 5\pmod 8$.